# You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before creating an application

Tags: twitter

I am trying to create a twitter app but i am gettiing this error

```
You must add your mobile phone to your Twitter profile before creating an application. Please read https://support.twitter.com/articles/110250-adding-your-mobile-number-to-your-account-via-web for more information.
```

I have added & activated my mobile in twitter but still same issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed it? Sometimes you need to wait for a while...

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error and I also added and confirmed my phone! any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a support ticket here https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform. Select the last option "I have an API policy question not covered by these points" and explain that you are still getting the error message after registering your phone.

I had the same issue and I think this resolved it - I didn't get a reply to my ticket but after half a day I could register the app successfully, of course it may just have been some batch process finally catching up.